# Unsure how to capture slash symbol "/" in my regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, url

I currently have a regular expression `/((http:\/\/.+(.net\/|.com\/))|^\/)(.+)$/gm` that extracts the relative URL of an absolute or relative path (I know that the path will either be a .com or .net domain, or it could just be the relative path altogether).

It works fine, except that I don't know how to get the slash into the last capturing group. Some examples:

```
http://google.com/abcd/efg (captures "abcd/efg", but I want "/abcd/efg")
http://google.com/abcd (captures "abcd", but I want "/abcd")
http://google.com/ (Fail)
http://google.com (Fail)
/abcd (captures "abcd", but I want "/abcd")
/ (Fail)
```

It feels like I am missing something obvious, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That regex syntax doesn't look like Java but more like Javascript. That being said you'll probably have to escape the slash, e.g. using `\/`.

Comment: Try [`/(http:\/\/.+(\.net|\.com)|^)(\/.+)$/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/8M1q8P/4)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew `http://google.com/abc/abc` causes strange behaviour. I think that the OP should capture each `/abc` into separate group and then concat

Comment: @xenteros: I find nothing strange with that.

Comment: @Thomas Oops, I was testing on regexr so I just copied the code from there, but I will ultimately use this in a Java program.

Comment: You should be careful when doing this since the regex engines might have different features (e.g. some support look-around some don't) and syntax issues like yours can lead to confusion. If you plan to use the expression in Java later then test it with the correct Java regex engine right from the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the pattern reordering and grouping construct boundary change you cannot achieve that.

In the `((http:\/\/.+(.net\/|.com\/))|^\/)` first capturing group, the `/` slash should be moved to the second group `(.+)`.

I suggest using

```
/(http:\/\/.+(\.net|\.com)|^)(\/.+)$/gm
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8M1q8P/4)

**Details**:

- `(http:\/\/.+(\.net|\.com)|^)` - Group 1:

  - `http:\/\/.+(\.net|\.com)` - `http://`, any 1+ chars other than linebreak chars, `.net` or `.com` captured into Group 2 (if this group is redundant, replace `(\.net|\.com)` with `\.(?:net|com)`)
  - `|` - or
  - `^`  - start of string
- `(\/.+)` - Group 3 (or 2): a `/` slash and any 1+ chars   other than line break chars.

Comment: Thank you, this works for my purposes! I didn't realize you could have the line start assertion by itself.

Answer (score 1):

What about this:

`(?<!(http:\/\/))\/[^\/]*`
each group is text between `/` incl and next `/` excl.

e.g.

for `http://google.com/abc/def/ghi` there will be four groups captured:

1. /google.com
2. /abc
3. /def
4. /ghi

Just concatinate all except the first one and you'll receive what's desired.